# does mono emulate .NET, or is it just a framework thats compatible with .NET languages?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Like, if I write a program on windows using C# and the .NET framework, then drop the code on a Linux machine running mono, will it run exactly the same? Or would I have to rewrite it to work with Mono's libraries?

Answer (score 5):

> will it run exactly the same? Or would I have to rewrite it to work with Mono's libraries?

This really depends on what your program does, and how it's written.

If you use pure C# and core .NET framework features that are supported on Mono, they will "just work", with no changes.  However, if you use unsupported features (ie: any 3rd party libs built around native interop, or WPF, etc), they will not work.

It's a very good idea to run the [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) regularly on your assemblies as you develop them.  This will tell you of any incompatibilities.

Comment: One key note is to also test your application on Mono/Linux directly. I have one application that fails to pass MoMA, but it in fact can run fine on Mono/Linux. I will try to report such false alarm later. :)

Comment: Besides, .NET application looks much different on Mono under openSUSE Linux theme :)

Comment: @Lex: True (about the look), but .NET applications look very different on XP vs. a themed W7 box, too ;)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: it depends.

Longer answer: Mono'c C# compiler produces IL which is the same as what .NET produces.

The problem is with the extras; i.e. using something in .NET for which there is no Mono library available (e.g. WPF).

Another area of incompatibility is where Win32-specific APIs are used.

So, sort of is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cross-platform implementation of C# and the implementation is compatible with .NET.

So, I'd say it's the former of the two options that you list.

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page